# Ruby - array of hashes group by based on similar hash key

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes who looks like :

```
[{"PROJECT"=>"awesome_project1","VERSION"=>128, "STATUS"=>"not required"},
 {"PROJECT"=>"awesome_project2", "VERSION"=>32, "STATUS"=>"finished"},
 {"PROJECT"=>"awesome_project1", "VERSION"=>64, "STATUS"=>"scheduled"}]
```

And I'm trying to merge the hashes based on one of the hask key, knowing that the key to group_by can change. So if I want to group_by "PROJECT" it would looks like :

```
[{"PROJECT"=>"awesome_project1","VERSION"=>[128,64], "STATUS"=>["not required","scheduled"]},
 {"PROJECT"=>"awesome_project2", "VERSION"=>32, "STATUS"=>"finished"}]
```

For the moment the closest I am to the result is by using group_by.

Do you have an idea on how to do it ?

Comment: It would be a kindness if you were to pretty print your objects rather than making us do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `group_by` and then `reduce` values merging them.

```
input.
  group_by { |h| h["PROJECT"] }.
  values.
  map do |v|
    v.reduce({}) do |acc, h|
      acc.merge(h) { |_, v1, v2| v1 == v2 ? v1 : [*v1, *v2] }
    end
  end

#⇒ [{"PROJECT"=>"awesome_project1",
#    "VERSION"=>[128, 64],
#    "STATUS"=>["not required", "scheduled"]},
#   {"PROJECT"=>"awesome_project2",
#    "VERSION"=>32,
#    "STATUS"=>"finished"}]
```

Comment: No need for `values.` since it is followed by `map`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always solve problems of this kind in one of two ways. The first is to use [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), as @Aleksei (aka mudsie) has done. The other way is to create a hash whose keys are the values over which the aggregation is being done (here the values of `"PROJEXT"`), then at the end extract the values of that hash. That's the approach I've taken below.

**Code**

```
def doit(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
    h.update(g["PROJECT"]=>(g.merge("STATUS"=>[g["STATUS"]]))) do |_,o1,n1|
      o1.merge(n1) { |k2,o2,n2| k2=="STATUS" ? (o2+n2) : o2 }  
    end
  end.values
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [
  {"PROJECT"=>"awesome_project1", "VERSION"=>128, "STATUS"=>"not required"},
  {"PROJECT"=>"awesome_project2", "VERSION"=> 32, "STATUS"=>"finished"},
  {"PROJECT"=>"awesome_project1", "VERSION"=> 64, "STATUS"=>"scheduled"}
]

doit arr
  #=> [{"PROJECT"=>"awesome_project1", "VERSION"=>128,
  #       "STATUS"=>["not required", "scheduled"]},
  #    {"PROJECT"=>"awesome_project2", "VERSION"=>32,
  #       "STATUS"=>["finished"]}]
```

This is not quite the return value you asked for. In the second hash you wanted `"STATUS"=>"finished"`, not `"STATUS"=>["finished"]`. I intentionally made the value an array, however, as it nearly always saves trouble down-the-line by making all values instances of the same class (here arrays). If it must be `"STATUS"=>"finished"`, let me know and I will edit my answer.

**Explanation**

...under construction